# C# Dictionary from mapped values

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a set of data stored in an object ReportModel like the following:

```
public class ReportModel
{
   public List<CarListingModel> CarListings {get; set;}
}

public class CarListingModel
{
   public long CarId {get; set;}
   public long OwnerId {get; set;}
   public string CarColor {get; set;}
}

public class GroupedListingModel
{
   public long OwnerId {get; set;}
   public int TotalCarCount {get; set;}
   public string CarColors {get; set;}
}
```

I've selected a set of data into the CarListingModel object like the following:

```
var list = someData.Where(...).Select(l => new CarListingModel 
{
       CarId = l.CarId,
       OwnerId = l.OwnerId,
       CarColor = l.Color
});
```

The code I'm using to get a TotalCarCount corresponding to each OwnerId looks like this:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(p=> p.OwnerId, p=> p.CarId, (key, g) => new GroupedListingModel  {
   OwnerId = key,
   TotalCarCount = g.Count()
}).ToList();
```

However, what I would like to do instead is to return a key-value pair where the value in an object containing multiple properties, for example, number of cars and a list of car colors. Something like this (which obviously doesn't work):

```
var result = list.GroupBy(p=> p.OwnerId, p=> p.CarId, p=> p.CarColor (key, g1, g2) => new GroupedListingModel  
{  OwnerId = key,
   TotalCarCount = g1.Count(),
   CarColors = string.Join(", ", g2.ToList());
}).ToList();
```

I have tried to create the grouped listing model differently, like this, but not sure if I'm on the right path:

```
public class GroupedListingModel_2
{
   public long OwnerId {get; set;}
   public DetailsModel Details {get; set;}
}

public class DetailsModel
{
   public int TotalCarCount {get; set;}
   public string CarColors {get; set;}
}
```

Now I'm thinking that this data would be better structured as a Dictionary, but again I am unsure of how to get from 'list' to my desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = list.GroupBy(p => p.OwnerId, (key, g) => new GroupedListingModel
{
    OwnerId = key,
    TotalCarCount = g.Count(),
    CarColors = string.Join(", ", g.Select(x => x.CarColor).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x)),
}).ToList()
```

But to keep data structured you can change your model a bit:

```
public class GroupedListingModel
{
    public long OwnerId { get; set; }
    public int TotalCarCount { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> CarColors { get; set; }
}
```

And the `GroupBy` result selector:

```
    CarColors = g.Select(x => x.CarColor)
```